# System.Drawing.Image to stream C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a `System.Drawing.Image` in my program. The file is not on the file system it is being held in memory. I need to create a stream from it. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public static Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat format) {
  var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  image.Save(stream, format);
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

Then you can use the following:

```
var stream = myImage.ToStream(ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Replace GIF with whatever format is appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: I was just writing that exact same thing!

Comment: System.Drawing.Image.Save requires a format when saving to a stream. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx

Comment: You can preserve the original image format by changing the image save statement to: image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);

Comment: When I call `image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);` it throws a "parameter null" exception for `encoder`, which is weird because I see clearly that there is an overload that only asks for the stream and the format. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: The issue of my previous comment is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242728/image-save-throws-exception-value-cannot-be-null-r-nparameter-name-encoder

Answer (score 16):

Use a memory stream

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, ...);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Stream ToStream(this Image image)
{
     var stream = new MemoryStream();

     image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
     stream.Position = 0;

     return stream;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using File Stream

```
 public Stream ToStream(string imagePath)
    {
    Stream stream=new FileStream(imagePath,FileMode.Open);
    return stream;
    }
```