# What is a structure of a standard POST request

Tags: c#, http, post

I am using C# for my project, can anyone tell me what is a standered structure of a HTTP POST Requset. How to attach POST data like a file in the Request from code.

Simply i want to create a POST request from my code itself, with diffrent items to be posted available.

I have checked Ietf's RFC for http POST but its too long....

Comment: What about using HttpWebRequest and letting it do the request formatting for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Specs for simple reference

I have always appreciated [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/) as a starting point.  It's small, concise and friendly.

Often you can get enough implementation details (or at least enough understanding) from this guide's simple style to suffice your need. It has worked for me many times. There is a section on [POST](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod). The guide builds cumulatively.

Additionally it links to proper specifications and fuller resources should you need to reference them and get into more detail.

### .NET Supporting Classes

Fortunately the .NET Framework Class Library contains higher level classes that can simplify your life. Look into the MSDN documentation and examples about [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) (doesn't lend itself as well to POST, favours GET for quick usage methods). Consider the more flexible [System.Web.HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) and [System.Web.HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) counterpart classes.

### Example using C#

This code sample shows the concept of posting binary data to a stream.

This method is called like:

```
PostMyData(Stream_instance, "http://url_to_post_to");
```

Namespaces involved are:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
```

The custom method would look something like the following.
**Note: Concept taken from [MSDN sample code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx).**

Although I use MIME type `application/octet-stream` for generic binary data, you can use any well known type from [this list of mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) to target the kind of binary data you are sending.

```
public int PostMyData(Stream binaryData, string postToUrl) {

    // make http request
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postToUrl);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; // binary data: 

    // data (bytes) that will be posted in body of request
    var streamOut = request.GetRequestStream();
    binaryData.CopyTo(streamOut);

    // post and get response
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
        var code = response.StatusCode;
        return (int)code;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but how do i add a Image in the POST data, i mean can i send the raw bytes or do i need to do somthing with it.

Comment: For C# code to stuff an image into a System.IO.Stream instance for passing into this function's `binaryData` parameter see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpWebRequest, its always the best way, but for a more simple aproach on Http Post read:
http://programaticallyspeaking.site40.net/blog/2010/11/how-to-implement-an-http-server-part-1/

Comment: Your blog only mentions GET,   Anyway good blog post keep it up.

Comment: Lol soz about that still haven't posted the post xDD

Comment: No problem, looking forward for you next post for POST ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found a way to view a sample POST request, Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to track HTTp transfers and click on RAW to view raw data being transfered.

Comment: Agreed. Fiddler is very good for inspecting HTTP traffic and learning from it.