# Convert a System.Drawing.Image to a stream

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.Drawing.Image to stream C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c)

how can I convert a System.Drawing.Image to a stream?

Comment: can you show your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: With ItextSharp -> Image.GetInstance(myStream)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can "Save" the image into a stream.

If you need a stream that can be read elsewhere, just create a `MemoryStream`:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

// If you're going to read from the stream, you may need to reset the position to the start
ms.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a reference to System.Drawing and include the following namespaces:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
```

And something like this should work:

```
public Stream GetStream(Image img, ImageFormat format)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, format);
    return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
Image.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

That's how I've done it when I needed to transmit an image in a stream from a web server.  (Note you can of course change the format).