# How to read an image to a Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.Drawing.Image to stream C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp)

```
 public static void SendHTMLEmail(Page p, string to, string subject, string content, System.Drawing.Image img)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");

            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            //message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("carboncopy@foo.bar.com"));
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = content;

            AlternateView htmlBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

            Stream s = new MemoryStream();

            //s.re

            LinkedResource pic = img; (Cannot assign an image to pic)
```

Since the pic requires a stream. I don't know how to read an image to a stream.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp

Comment: @WebWorld can you please post it as a answer so I can mark this question solved?