# What's the recommended way to load an internal file on the web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

We've got a certain image in the `\Images` folder of our web site.  We need to include that image in an OpenXml file we're generating internally, and for that we're using the following snippet:

```
var logo = Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\logo-new.png");
var imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png); // mainPart is of type MainDocumentPart
using (var stream = new FileStream(logo, FileMode.Open))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
```

Then later `imagePart` is used for embedding in the document.

This code works fine in development, but in deployment we're getting a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when we try to open the file for streaming.

Clearly there is an access permission problem, since `Server.MapPath()` is converting the web path to an absolute path on the server drive, and the IIS user doesn't have rights to that.  We might be able to get around it by granting access to everyone, but something tells me that this is not the textbook way of doing it.  Surely there must be a way of accessing this file that doesn't require us to start futzing with access permissions to the web deployment folder?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by including the file as a resource rather than by trying to access it through the file system:

```
var logo = Resources.logo_new;
var imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
using (var stream = logo.ToStream(ImageFormat.Png))
{
    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
}
```

Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668493/7850) for the `.ToStream()` extension.