# Create google.cloud.vision.v1.image from System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-vision

I'm currently using the following code to create an `google.cloud.vision.v1.image` from a local file

```
var image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

In order to save bandwidth and processing time, I need to resize this image before sending it for processing. I can resize a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` but how can I create `google.cloud.vision.v1.image` from this Bitmap.

Can someone please point me to the documentation of this class?

Comment: @John Skeet Please help me on this one...

Comment: What's wrong with `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromStream()`?

Comment: @haim770 Can i create it from a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` directly?

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting is that you're using the [`Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.html)'s `FromFile()` method, not .NET's [`System.Drawing.Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.8)'s.

Google's Image class is merely a wrapper that allows you to call their services. It doesn't contain resize methods or the likes.

So you'll have to [resize a local image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp), then [write it to a stream in the desired format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp), then construct Google's Image class from a stream.

That code would look something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Image sourceImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
System.Drawing.Image resizedImage = ResizeImage(sourceImage, width: 800, height: 600);
System.IO.Stream imageStream = resizedImage.ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image resizedImageToUpload = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.FromStream(imageStream);
```

And of course you'd need a `using() { ... }` or `Dispose()` here or there.

Comment: Thanks... so there is no other way other than creating a stream?

Comment: Sure, you could write it to disk. Using a `FileStream`.