# How do I save my image list which is an image type to a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an image list and I want to save these objects to a folder. But I haven't found any way for this problem. Buy the way, the list includes images. I mean, It hasn't a string, base64 or something like that. Also, I'm getting these images with jquery ajax from the frontend. The last one, my images inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. Thank you!
The function is here:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string ImageSave(Image[] image_objects)// images coming with ajax
    {
        //I want to save the images here.

        return "OK!";
    }
```

Comment: First, welcome to SO! Second, you could take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp. I would start to transform each `Image` to a `Stream`, then write each stream to disc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but, my images inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image. I mean Images have no Save function. I can't use this way.