# OpenFile Dialog Box keeps resources open

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

After opening a photo in my application using the Openfile Dialog I cannot do anything with the file unless I close my application.  I have placed the OpenFile Dialog in a using statement and tried various ways to release resources with no success.  How can I release the process to avoid the error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

```
       using (OpenFileDialog GetPhoto = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            GetPhoto.Filter = "images | *.jpg";
            if (GetPhoto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pbPhoto.Image = Image.FromFile(GetPhoto.FileName);
                txtPath.Text = GetPhoto.FileName;
                txtTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(GetPhoto.Fi‌​leName);
                //GetPhoto.Dispose();  Tried this
                //GetPhoto.Reset();  Tried this
                //GC.Collect(): Tried this
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not (OpenFileDialog) your problem is for PictureBox 
you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_PictureBox_ImageLocation) for load image or if this not works
do this for load image

```
        OpenFileDialog GetPhoto = new OpenFileDialog();
        GetPhoto.Filter = "images | *.jpg";
        if (GetPhoto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path: GetPhoto.FileName,mode: FileMode.Open);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fs);
            fs.Close(); // End using
            fs.Dispose();
            pbPhoto.Image = bitmap;
            txtPath.Text = GetPhoto.FileName;
            txtTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(GetPhoto.Fi‌​leName);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the explanation as to the actual problem.  This worked.

Comment: An issue has come up using this code.  When I try to save the image to my SQL DB I now get an error.  My code for saving the image is                                    
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 pbPhoto.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();

Comment: Charles it is my Email if you need more help amirhoseinadlfar@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the doc for [`Image.FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile):

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

So you could try to make a copy of the image and then release an original `Image`:

```
using (OpenFileDialog GetPhoto = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    GetPhoto.Filter = "images | *.jpg";
    if (GetPhoto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromFile(GetPhoto.FileName))
        {
            pbPhoto.Image = (Image) image.Clone(); // Make a copy
            txtPath.Text = GetPhoto.FileName;
            txtTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(GetPhoto.Fi‌​leName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If it not help, you could try to make a copy via the `MemoryStream` and the [`Image.FromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method: [System.Drawing.Image to stream C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp)

Comment: Why do you need to copy the image? I would assume just having the using statement with the image would solve the problem...

Comment: @Chrisi `Image` is a class (that is a reference type). When it assigned to `pbPhoto.Image` property and then disposed, access to that property leads to `ObjectDisposedException`.